# Why $(T-\lambda I)^{2n} (v) = 0$ implies $(T-\lambda I)^{n} (v) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why $(T-\lambda I)^{2n} (v) = 0$ implies $(T-\lambda I)^{n} (v) = 0$?

This is used when proving that $ V= ker (T - \lambda I )^n \oplus Im (T - \lambda I )^n$

Comment: You are, of course, in a space with $\;\dim V=n\;$ , right?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $n$ is the dimension of the vector space $V$, and $T$ is a linear endomorphism of $V$. Call $A=(T-\lambda I)$.

For every $k=0,1,\dots,2n$, call $V_k$ the span of $\{A^kv,A^{k+1}v,\dots,A^{2n}v\}$. By hypothesis, $\dim V_{0}\leq n$, and $\dim V_{2n}=0$.

**Lemma:** $V_{k+1}=A(V_k)$.

*Proof:* Since $A^{2n}v=0$, $V_{k+1}=\mathrm{Span}\{A^{k+1}v,\dots,A^{2n}v\}=A\left(\mathrm{Span}\{A^{k}v,\dots,A^{2n-1}v\}\right)=A\left(\mathrm{Span}\{A^{k}v,\dots,A^{2n}v\}\right)=A(V_k)$.

**Corollary:** If $\dim V_k\neq 0$, then $\dim V_{k+1}=\dim V_k-1$.

*Proof:* Clearly, $\dim V_k-1\leq \dim V_{k+1}\leq\dim V_k$.

If $V_k\neq 0$ and $V_{k+1}=A(V_k)=V_k$, then $V_{k+2}=A(V_{k+1})=A(V_k)=V_k$ and so on, by induction $0\neq V_k=V_{2n}=0$, absurd.

Hence, $V_{k+1}\subsetneq V_k$ and $\dim V_{k+1}=\dim V_k-1$.

Now, if $V_0$ has dimension $m$, $V_m$ has dimension $0$ thanks to the corollary. But $m\leq n$ and so $V_n=0$, too. In particular, $A^nv\in V_n$ is $0$.

Comment: I can't understand the proof of your corollary. Why $V_{k+1} = A(V_k) = V_k$. And why if $V_0$ has dimension m, then $V_m$ has dimension 0.

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction: I'm *assuming* $V_{k+1}=V_k$, and then I come to an absurd. And if $V_0$ has dimension $m$, thanks to the corollary $V_1$ has dimension $m-1$, $V_2$ has dimension $m-2$... $V_m$ has dimension $0$.